# Dynamic insert function

Tags: excel

*It is a requirement that I use Excel to solve this issue.*

In `col A` I have `0`s and `1`s with various quantities of `0`s between the `1`s. Every time a `1` appears I want the difference between two numbers given in two columns next to my binary column. However I wish to get the results from this calculation stated next to the previous `1`.

I'd cope with different software, but how do I achieve this with Excel?

Comment: What do you mean by "stated next to the previous one"?? Is it in the top of the fourth column with no spaces between each result, not corresponding to the results respective line?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Assume you a one in row 3 and again in row 7. Then you got two numbers for subtraction in row 7, and the result needs to be in row 3. Further if the next one is located in row 13 the results from that row must be in row 7 etc

Comment: I believe you only option is to use VBA code.

Comment: Alright.. Do you have any short hints on functions to use? Or do vba follow normal programming syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `=IF(A4=1,OFFSET(B4,MATCH(1,A5:A$1000,0),0)-OFFSET(C4,MATCH(1,A5:A$1000,0),),"")`

in `D4` and copied down to suit seems to work.

Edit:

`=(IF(A$=1,             ,"")` is as in: [IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx) where value if false is (*blank*), expressed as "".

The `value_if_true` is the difference between `ColumnB` and `ColumnC` values, each ‘located’ from an OFFSET function as in [=OFFSET(reference,rows,cols,height,width)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324991).

`reference`s are to the appropriate column for the row into which the formula is inserted (ie `B4` and `C4`) from which the values required are ‘south’ by a variable amount.

[MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx), as in =MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type]) is to determine the extent of the offset on a case-by-case basis. In reverse order, the parameters here are `match_type` = `0` (to require an exact match) and `lookup_array` is as much of ColumnA as required. Initially chosen as up to Row1000 (by `A$1000`) but can be extended as far as necessary, subject to row limit for the relevant Excel version.

The first parameter `lookup_value`) is of course `1` since that is the flag for the rows that contain the values to be subtracted.

Without a `$` between `A` and `5` in the MATCH functions the size of the array automatically decreases (top cell row reference increases) as the formula is copied down, hence finds the *next* instance (rather than the same one over and over again).

Comment: I got literally no idea of what it does but its working. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Nice to know there's something like it. Avoid coding is always better.

Comment: @pnuts mate you did good! You can either way go home and have a nice weekend. The explanation makes perfectly sense. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

With VBA, I'd first set the formulas to show results in same line as the "ones". (Suppose I used the D column for that.)

= if(A1 = 1; B1 - C1; "")

Then, in VBA window, do the following:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim Filled as Collection
Set Filled = new Colleciton  'this collection will stored filled lines

'store filled lines
for i = 2 to 1000 'use your table limit
    if Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" then 'the 4 is for D column, i for the line
        Filled.Add i
    end if
next

'now fill the E column with displaced values
for i = 1 to Filled.Count - 1
    Sheet1.Cells(Filled(i), 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(Filled(i+1), 5).Value
next

'please note there's a missing line (the last), it's up to you to decide how to fill it
'sorry I cannot debug this code
```

I'd associate that to some sheet event or to a button.

Comment: If sheet is too large, set `Application.ScreenUpdating` to false before code, and don't forget to get it back to `true` at the end.